# cannot use + when try to add number

Tags: javascript

After i selected option 1 and after i add the number like 100 it results like this 100100

This is the code:

```
var userAmount;
    var userMoney = 100;
    var totalMoney;
    alert("1. Add");
    alert("2. Subtraction");
    var userOption = prompt("Enter your selection: ");
        if (userOption == 1) {
            userAmount = prompt("Amount: ");
            var totalMoney = userMoney + userAmount;
            alert("Total is " + totalMoney);
        }
        else {
            userAmount = prompt("Amount: ");
            var totalMoney = userMoney - userAmount;
            alert("Total is" + totalMoney);
        }
```

Comment: `prompt` returns string, not a number

Comment: Use `Number(userAmount)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there is an implicit conversion when you are using `+`. In your case `+` is actually concatenating the values.

The function **[prompt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.prompt)** returns a string so when you are adding it to an int it is concatenating the values. It takes both the values as string and concatenates the value instead of adding it.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators) says that:

> **String operators**
>
> In addition to the comparison operators, which can be used on string
>   values, the concatenation operator (+) concatenates two string values
>   together, returning another string that is the union of the two
>   operand strings. For example, "my " + "string" returns the string "my
>   string".

You need to cast it like `Number(userAmount)` Something like:

```
var totalMoney = userMoney + Number(userAmount);
```

or

```
userAmount = parseFloat(prompt("Amount: "));
```

so you need to cast both the values to an int so that `+` operator behaves as addition instead of string concatenation.

Comment: @Mr.AZ: welcome to [so]. To mark a solution as the best one for you (the questioner), you can accept an answer by clicking the big tick just underneath the vote arrows on the left of an answer. I'd highly recommend taking a quick look at what [so] is [about] -- it's just a quick intro into how our community runs. Good luck -- it's great that we were able to answer your question!

Answer (score 2):

A common mistake for people new to *JavaScript* is they forget almost every value taken from user input is a *String*. You'll need to convert these into numbers before you can use the addition `+` operator. This conversion can be done with the [**unary `+`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#-_.28Unary_Plus.29) or [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat), for example

```
userAmount = parseFloat(prompt("Amount: "));
```

When using *Strings* in *JavaScript*, the `+` operator is actually string concatenation

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast your values to integers first. Try using parseInt()

change:

```
var totalMoney = userMoney + userAmount;
```

to this:

```
var totalMoney = parseInt(userMoney, 10) + parseInt(userAmount, 10);
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to convert userMoney though - its already a number.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the user given number is actually a string.

A quick way to fix it is to type:

```
var totalMoney = userMoney + userAmount * 1;
```