# Javascript either parseInt or + , appending instead of adding

Tags: javascript, string

i'm having some trouble with the parseInt function or + operand.  I want to take in two numbers, multiply one by a third number and add them together.  Instead of adding the numbers it appends one number to another.

```
<script language = 'JavaScript'>
function calculate_total()
{
var a = 0;
var b = 0;
var t = 0;

    parseInt(a = prompt('Pay 1'), 10);
//Input of 10
        if(isNaN(a))
        {
            alert('Error A');
        }
//No Error

    parseInt(b = prompt('Pay 2'), 10);
//input of 12
        if(isNaN(b))
        {
            alert('Error B');
        }
//No Error

    parseInt(t = (a * 20 + b), 10);
        if(isNaN(t))
        {
            alert('Error T');
        }
        else
        {
            alert('Total Pay: ' + t);
//expected answer 212
//Actual Answer 20012
        }
//No Error
}
calculate_total();
</script>
```

Comment: and [cannot use + when try to add number](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20719319/218196) (and many more)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
parseInt(a = prompt('Pay 1'), 10);
...
parseInt(b = prompt('Pay 2'), 10);
...
parseInt(t = (a * 20 + b), 10);
```

Here `a`, `b` and `t`, all have got string data only and when it is converted to an int, its discarded immediately. So, fix them like this

```
a = parseInt(prompt('Pay 1'), 10);
...
b = parseInt(prompt('Pay 2'), 10);
...
t = a * 20 + b;
```

According to [ECMA Script's specifications for Additive operation,](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.1)

> 7 If Type(lprim) is String or Type(rprim) is String, then Return the
>   String that is the result of concatenating ToString(lprim) followed by
>   ToString(rprim)

So when you use a string and number with `+` operator, result will be concatenation of both the operands.

According to [ECMA Script's specifications for Multiplicative operation,](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.5)

> 1. Let left be the result of evaluating MultiplicativeExpression.
> 2. Let leftValue be GetValue(left).
> 3. Let right be the result of evaluating UnaryExpression.
> 4. Let rightValue be GetValue(right).
> 5. Let leftNum be ToNumber(leftValue).
> 6. Let rightNum be ToNumber(rightValue).

`*` operator basically converts both the operands to numbers. So, the result will be proper even if both the operands are numbers in strings.

You can confirm the above mentioned things with this

```
var a = "100", b = "12";
console.log(a * 20);      // Prints 2000, both operands are converted to numbers
console.log(a * 20 + b);  // Prints 200012, as b is string, both are concatenated
```

Comment: Thank you this works and the explanation is easy to understand

Answer (score 4):

I'm not a Javascript expert by any means, but you seem to be ignoring the result of `parseInt`, instead storing just the result of `prompt()` in your `a`, `b` and `t` variables. I'd expect this:

```
parseInt(a = prompt('Pay 1'), 10);
```

to be:

```
a = parseInt(prompt('Pay 1'), 10);
```

(And the same for the other prompts.)

At that point, the variables' values will be the numbers rather than the strings, so `+` should add them appropriately.

Comment: Thank you this works and the explanation is easy to understand

Answer (score 1):

You parsing result which is already wrong due to appending as string:

try updating following statements:

```
a = parseInt(prompt('Pay 1'), 10);
b = parseInt(prompt('Pay 2'), 10);
t = a * 20 + b;  // no need to parse as a and b already integers
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
a = parseInt(prompt('pay 1'),10);
```

etc. for b and t.
Now you declare a as `prompt('pay 1')` and not as the int value returned by `parseInt`.

Answer (score 1):

`parseInt()` returns an integer value. And you dony need `parseInt(string, 10)`, for `parseInt` decimal system used by defaults.

```
a = parseInt(prompt('Pay 1'));
b = parseInt(prompt('Pay 2'));
t = a * 20 + b;
```

Answer (score -1):

I've fixed the code for you:

```
<script language = 'JavaScript'>
function calculate_total()
{
var a = 0;
var b = 0;
var t = 0;

    a = parseInt(prompt('Pay 1'), 10);
//Input of 10
        if(isNaN(a))
        {
            alert('Error A');
        }
//No Error

    b = parseInt(prompt('Pay 2'), 10);
//input of 12
        if(isNaN(b))
        {
            alert('Error B');
        }
//No Error

    t = parseInt(a * 20 + b, 10);
        if(isNaN(t))
        {
            alert('Error T');
        }
        else
        {
            alert('Total Pay: ' + t);
//expected answer 212
//Actual Answer 20012
        }
//No Error
}
calculate_total();
</script>
```

Comment: I think the OP would learn more if you also explained *what* you changed and *why*.